# Нужна ли запятая в предложении и почему?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, междометие

"Ага(,) и потом на меня донесут учителю".

Я считаю, что запятая нужна после "ага", а мне говорят, что не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Да, запятая нужна.

***Ага, и потом на меня донесут учителю.*** (В зависимости от интонации можно даже и восклицательный знак поставить.)

> **АГА** [aha]. **I. *межд.*** Выражает злорадство, торжество, замешательство и т.п. *Ага, дрожишь! Ага, не уйдёшь!*

> 2. выражение удивления, радости; указание на то, что человек что-то узнал, понял, сообразил, придумал и т. д. ◆ Я ничего не понимаю… Татьяна Алексеевна. Влюблены? **Ага!** Покраснел! *А. П. Чехов, «Юбилей», 1892 г.* ◆  — **Ага,** так вам нравится наш новый эхолот, — одобрительно посмотрел на юношу Ганешин. *И. А. Ефремов, «Атолл Факаофо», 1944 г.*

> 1. межд. Восклицание с торжествующей интонацией. *Ага! попался!*
> 2. частица. Выражает подтверждение, а также уяснение или догадку (прост.). *Ага, вот в чём дело-то! Видишь? Ага, вижу.*

Источники: [Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?word=%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0&all=x),  [Викисловарь](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0),  [Академик.ру](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/3422).

Comment: Образцовые у вас ответы!!  И спасибо за вашу работу на форуме.  Без вас он похож на наш снежный апрель, где всё покрыто льдом и снегом, а по парку бродят замерзающие утки...

Comment: Спасибо! Вы, как всегда, тянете этот форум. Вот и Nektoid опять потерялся.

Comment: Я вот тоже думаю: надо его найти. Вчера даже адрес записала на всякий случай. Таким людям нужно больше внимания, общения, интересных обсуждений... Иногда тоже думаю: не буду отвечать, никому ничего не нужно. Но ведь люди приходят, спрашивают, надеются на нашу помощь...